PackagesNotFound error even when verified packages as installed
I am trying to follow this tutorial for BERT topic modeling:
https://jpcompartir.github.io/BertopicR/
library(reticulate) 
reticulate::install_miniconda()
library(BertopicR)
BertopicR::check_python_dependencies()

This gives me the error:
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - pytorch==2.0.0

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge
  - defaults

When I run pip show torch, it seems to verify that the correct package is installed.
Name: torch
Version: 2.0.0
Summary: Tensors and Dynamic neural networks in Python with strong GPU acceleration
Home-page: https://pytorch.org/

However, if I try conda install pytorch I get the same error about not being available from current channels.
I've tried updating, reinstalling torch, restarting, etc. and nothing seems to change this error.
